# SQL Server Stretch Cluster

Tags: sql-server

I would like a SQL Server instance on a VM in Azure to be in sync with an on premise SQL Server so applications on the VM and applications on premise are using the same in sync data.  Could a stretch cluster provide this or is a stretch cluster only for fail-over?

Answer (score 1):

[At least three flavors of business continuity](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/sql-server-business-continuity-dr) are built into MS SQL Server:

- Always On Availability Groups replication
- Always On failover cluster instance
- Log shipping

[Stretch Cluster](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-replica/stretch-cluster-replication-using-shared-storage) refers to a cluster between independent storage using storage replication. You can put anything you like on these disks, including databases. However, you must take care to preserve write order, and have some procedure for failing over SQL Server.  Which may involve layering on Always On FCI, or more manual steps.

Availability Groups does not require storage replication as it uses database aware replication. There also are well documented [procedures to extend your Always On Availability Group to Azure](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-sql-high-availability-dr).

Comment: Thank you.  I have scheduled a full day next week to study the various flavors of continuity you provided.  In the meantime, I'm curious, is Log shipping possible over WAN?

Comment: Many things are possible. How to properly secure connections and onramp to Azure is another topic entirely.  Talk to your networking,  DBA, and Azure support about the design. Ask specific questions here or over at  https://dba.stackexchange.com/